# How to use pytorch dynamic graph property to train a model parallel with different hyperparamters?

Tags: pytorch

Is there a standard way to train multiple models with pytorch by leveraging fro dynamic graph property?

Comment: What do you mean? To train different models, you instatiate models with different hyper-parameters

Comment: yeah to train different models sharing the same data loader. Can you please refer to a training loop code.

Answer (score 0):

DataLoader is independent of the model. Here's an example of what you can do.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    # Model definition

#Two models with different hyper-parameters
model1 = Model(args) 
model2 = Model(args)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(args)

for data in dataloader:
    # Train model1

for data in dataloader:
    # Train model2
```